# On file opening document tabs are messed up

Tags: html, css, git, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I've searched around for a solution to this issue!. When I open a file ( html, js, css ) in Sublime Text 3 (also 2) all the previous file indention is messed up, with there being a mixture of spaces and indentations.

The repositories I work with use hard tabs.

Heres my process ->

1. Save file with indentation
2. Commit file using git
3. -- Here I either push the changes, or if working with an SVN use rebase.
4. Either pull down from the repositry or svn dcommit.
5. Re-open the file, scratch head and cry a little at the messed up indentation.

I've modified my sublime settings to try and solve this issue... 
they are

```
{
"color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Flatland/Flatland Monokai.tmTheme",
"disable_formatted_linebreak": true,
"flatland_sidebar_tree_large": true,
"flatland_square_tabs": true,
"font_face" : "Source Code Pro",
"font_options":
[
    "no_bold",
    "subpixel_antialias"
],
"font_size": 14,
"highlight_line": true,
"highlight_modified_tabs": true,
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage"
],
"line_padding_bottom": 2,
"line_padding_top": 2,
"scroll_speed": 0.2,
"tab_size": 4,
"theme": "Flatland Dark.sublime-theme",
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
"trim_automatic_white_space": true,
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
"detect_indentation": false,
"word_wrap": "true"
```

}

If you would like to see a screenshot of the issue please ask, for some reason i'm not allowed to post images yet!

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! What exactly is the difference between the settings you posted and the default. Also, in my experience, hard tabs aren't the greatest. Have you tried making a dummy file with different indentation levels only with spaces instead of tabs in step 1, and see how it comes out at step 6? also, what editor are you using at step 1?

Comment: Hi Amp, we're all working with hard tabs so changing them is not an option. I use sublime text 3 for all my files. I haven't tried making a dummy file but will do now.